# Recorrer array de objetos hasta llegar a sus propiedades en js

Tags: javascript, html, array

Tengo una función en la cual le paso un elemento de tipo string y quiero compararlo con con una propiedad que cada objeto que compone el Array tienen. Si coincide me devuelve true y sino false.

```js
function Carta(id, marca, puntos) {
    this.id = id;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.puntos = puntos;

    //GETTER
    this.getId = function () {
        return this.id;
    }

    this.getMarca = function () {
        return this.marca;
    }

    this.getPuntos = function () {
        return this.puntos;
    }
}

lambo1 = new Carta("lambo1", "lamborghini", 25);
lambo2 = new Carta("lambo2", "lamborghini", 25);
bmw1 = new Carta("bmw1", "bmw", 25);
bmw2 = new Carta("bmw2", "bmw", 25);
volks1 = new Carta("volks1", "volkswagen", 25);
volks2 = new Carta("volks2", "volkswagen", 25);
nissan1 = new Carta("nissan1", "nissan", 25);
nissan2 = new Carta("nissan2", "nissan", 25);

function verificarCampo(elemento){
    for (i=0; i<=baraja.length; i++) {
        if(baraja[i]."objeto"."elementoObjeto"==elemento){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero en la comprobacion "if(baraja[i]."objeto"."elementoObjeto"==elemento)" no se como escribirla correctamente ya que cada objeto tiene un nombre distinto...

Dentro de cada objeto sus propiedades tienen mismos nombres. Alguien sabe como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes poner la estructura de la baraja y las propiedades de cada objeto, que supongo es una carta?

Comment: si por supuesto

Comment: Ok, pusiste los constructores. ¿A qué propiedades se mapean esos tres parámetros? Dijiste que cada objeto tiene nombres distintos. Te refieres a que cada carta es instanciada en una variable distinta? ¿Baraja es un array plano de todas las cartas?

Comment: Aprovecho de preguntar: qué propiedad quieres verificar? El id o la marca?

Comment: Pregunta final: tu función tiene por objetivo comprobar si una carta de la baraja se llama igual que el string que le pasaste?

Comment: eso es, le paso un parametro a la funcion y dependiendo de si coincide o no devuelve true o false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la baraja es un array que agrupa las cartas:

```
var baraja=[];
baraja.push( new Carta("lambo1", "lamborghini", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("lambo2", "lamborghini", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("bmw1", "bmw", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("bmw2", "bmw", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("volks1", "volkswagen", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("volks2", "volkswagen", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("nissan1", "nissan", 25));
baraja.push( new Carta("nissan2", "nissan", 25));
```

Y quieres una función que verifique que si la carta "nissan2" está en la baraja, harías

```
function cartaExiste(id_carta){
    var existe=false;
    for (i=0; i < baraja.length; i++) {
        if(baraja[i].getId() == id_carta ){
            existe = true;
        }
    }
    return existe;
}
```

Ojo que el bucle termina en `i < baraja.length` y no en `i <= baraja.length`. Los arrays comenzan en cero.

Hay una manera más elegante de hacerlo que es usando `array.filter`

```
function cartaExiste(id_carta){
    var matching = baraja.filter(function(carta) {
      return carta.getId() == id_carta;
    });
    return matching.length>0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría haber empleado el método [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) para comparar el `getter` con el valor pasado por parámetro , y si retorna `undefined` es porque no se encuentra dicho elemento, con esto ultimo podríamos hacer la comprobación para el `return`;

```
function verificarCampo(elemento){
    let obj = baraja.find(o => o.getId() === elemento);
    return obj !== undefined;
}
```